# Derivative of the function

Tags: derivatives, optimization

Given $b$ is a $p\times 1$, $X_{n\times p}$ and $y_{n\times 1}$ matrix, then what is the derivative of the following function with respect to $b$:

$$
(y-Xb)'  \sin(y-Xb)
$$

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096581/derivative-of-a-vector/1096655#1096655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, define the vector variable$$w=Xb-y$$Then write the function using the Frobenius Inner Product (denoted by a colon) and this new variable. In this form, it is easier to find the differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= w:\sin(w) \cr\cr
df &= dw:\sin(w) + w:d\sin(w) \cr
   &= \sin(w):dw + w:\cos(w)\circ dw \cr
   &= \sin(w):dw + w\circ\cos(w):dw \cr
   &= \big(\sin(w) + w\circ\cos(w)\big):dw \cr
   &= \big(\sin(w) + w\circ\cos(w)\big):X\,db \cr\cr
   &= X^T\big(\sin(w) + w\circ\cos(w)\big):db \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial b} &= X^T\big(\sin(w) + w\circ\cos(w)\big) \cr\cr
}$$
Where $\circ$ is used to denote the Hadamard (aka element-wise) product. And the trig functions are applied element-wise, as well.

Rules for manipulating Frobenius products can be found by considering the trace equivalence $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$ Typing "frobenius inner product" into the search field at the top of this page will lead you to many other answers on this site, which may contain more details.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry is it $Xb-y$ or $y-Xb$?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Sine is an odd-function, therefore $$(-w)\sin(-w)=(w)\sin(w)$$

Comment: I have a small question. Is $w\circ cos(w)$ a $n\times 1$ vector?

Comment: Yes, $w$ has the same shape as $y$. All Hadamard products have the same shape as their operands. So if I write $A=B\circ C$ you know that $(A,B,C)$ are all matrices (or vectors) with identical dimensions.

Comment: so if I have $A=B\circ C$ then can I write $A/B=C$ where $A/B$ is elementwise?

Comment: Not in general, but if none of the elements of B equals zero then yes, you can do that.